# Trying to use OpenGL Texture Compression on a large bitmap - get white squares

Tags: opengl, compression, textures

I'm trying to use OpenGL's texture compression on a large image. My image is a world map that I'm painting on the screen as a series of 128x128 tiles as part of a learning exercise. I want the user to be able to pan and zoom around the image. It's a JPG that is rather large (20k by 10k pixels) and so I wanted each of my tiles (I tiled the image) to be compressed in order to lower the memory footprint of my program.

I picked an arbitrary texture compression format when I called glTexImage2D and each of my tiles become white squares. I dug a little deeper into this and figured "maybe my video card doesn't support all these formats." The video card is an Nvidia NVS 3100M on an IBM ThinkPad laptop and I did a glGetString to try to see what the supported texture compression formats were, but it didn't return anything (GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS). I also checked what GL_EXTENSIONS were supported and it returned "GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_paletted_texture" which doesn't look like much.

My program is in C# using the SharpGL library.

What other things can I check to see to try to figure this one out?

Comment: You don't use `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS` with [`glGetString`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetString). You use it with [`glGetIntegerv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGet). Also, what OpenGL version do you have? What are your `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER`?

Comment: My GL_VERSION is 1.1.0 and my GL_RENDERER is "GDI Generic". Strangely the C# SharpGL library doesn't allow me to get at the GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMAT with the glGetInteger function. The API has an enumeration that it takes and it's not one of the options.

Comment: You're not getting hardware acceleration. That's a much bigger problem. Do you have proper drivers installed? Is Optimus set to switch to the NVIDIA card correctly (if you have that)? Try running the [OpenGL Extension Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php) and see what version you get with that.

Comment: You were dead on. I updated my XAML code where I was adding my OpenGL control. I added an attribute called RenderContextType="FBO". I'm assuming that FBO stands for "frame buffer object"? I think that SharpGL is hiding this from me, the programmer which it what tripped me up. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the alpha channel of the original bitmap. Save it as 32bit bitmap with alpha channel and try.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking those texture minification filtering settings?